# Project Euler # 19 Counting Sundays in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, datetime

> You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some research for yourself.
>
> 1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
> Thirty days has September,
> April, June and November.
> All the rest have thirty-one,
> Saving February alone,
> Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.
> And on leap years, twenty-nine.
> A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a century unless it is divisible by 400.
>
> How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?

```
day_names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
month_names = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September',
               'October', 'November', 'December']
month_days_common = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
month_to_days = dict(zip(month_names, month_days_common))


def is_leap(year):
    """return True if a year is leap. False otherwise."""
    if (year % 4) == 0:
        if (year % 100) == 0:
            if (year % 400) == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        return False


def get_date_day_names(end_year):
    """return a list of tuples containing day name, day, month, year from 1900 to end_year(exclusive)."""
    start_year = 1900
    total = 0
    all_day_names = []
    all_months1 = []
    all_months2 = {}
    year_month_times_number_of_days = []
    final_dates = []
    for year in range(start_year, end_year):
        count = 0
        while count < 12:
            all_months1.append((year, month_names[count]))
            count += 1
    for year in range(start_year, end_year):
        if is_leap(year):
            total += 366
        else:
            total += 365
    for i in range(total):
        all_day_names.append(day_names[i % 7])
    for year, month in all_months1:
        if is_leap(year):
            if month == 'February':
                all_months2[(year, month)] = 29
            else:
                all_months2[(year, month)] = month_to_days[month]
        else:
            all_months2[(year, month)] = month_to_days[month]
    for date, number_of_days in all_months2.items():
        for i in range(number_of_days):
            year_month_times_number_of_days.append((date, i + 1))
    date_day_name = list(zip(all_day_names, year_month_times_number_of_days))
    for date_item in date_day_name:
        final_dates.append((date_item[0], date_item[1][1], date_item[1][0][1], date_item[1][0][0]))
    return final_dates


def count(day_name, day_of_the_month, end_year):
    """returns count of a given day from 1901 to end_year(exclusive)"""
    final_dates = []
    dates_1900_to_end_year = get_date_day_names(end_year)
    for date in dates_1900_to_end_year:
        if date[-1] != 1900 and date[0] == day_name and date[1] == day_of_the_month:
            final_dates.append(date)
    return len(final_dates)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(count('Sunday', 1, 2001))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## whole algorithmic change => \$O(n)\$

Your existing algorithm is quite confusing. Perhaps instead you could try a simpler structure such as:

```py
from datetime import date

def num_sundays_on_first_of_month(year1, year2):
  num_sundays = 0
  for i in range(year1, year2+1):
      for j in range(1, 13):
          if date(i, j, 1).weekday() == 6:
              num_sundays += 1
  return num_sundays

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(num_sundays_on_first_of_month(1901,2000))
```

This code is much more readable and *far* briefer. It makes effective use of the [`datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) and its `date` objects.  It works by looping through every month between `year1` and `year2` inclusive and counting if it is a Sunday.

This runs at \$O(n)\$ time where \$n = year2 - year1\$

Comment: Yeah, you have a point, I sometimes overcomplicate stuff. The whole point was trying not to use modules and I did it for fun I guess.

Comment: If you don't. Want to use modules, The date class is a very simple object that can easily be added to your program.